# Weak convergence of a collection of random variables starting from a random index

Tags: probability-theory

Imagine for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds:
$$ (X_{r}^{(1)}, X_{r}^{(2)} \dots X_{r}^{(k)}) \Rightarrow (Y_1, Y_2, \dots,
Y_k), $$
where $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_k$ are i.i.d. random variables.

Let $\kappa_r$ be a surely finite random variable such that for any $r$
$$ \sigma(\kappa_r) \amalg \sigma(X_{r}^{(\kappa_r)}, X_{r}^{(\kappa_r +
1)}, \dots) $$

Is it true that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$(X_{r}^{(\kappa_r)}, X_{r}^{(\kappa_r + 1)} \dots, X_{r}^{(\kappa_r + n - 1)})
\Rightarrow (Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n),$$

Given just one of the below

1. $\kappa_r$ is bounded a.s. as $r \to \infty$.
2. $\kappa_r$ is bounded in probability as $r \to \infty$.